# Cocoa 517 error code/ write to file Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, xcode, file

```
NSArray * Path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * documentsDirectory=[Path objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Paragraph.txt",documentsDirectory];
NSError * error;
NSString * content=Content;
NSLog(content);

BOOL Ok=[content writeToFile:filename atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];
if(!Ok){
    NSLog(@" Error %@,",[error localizedDescription]);     
}
```

As you can see, I try to write a file to iphone simulator file with this code block, but it doestn work i get  "error 517 operation could not be completed" my documents file exitst there. and i put Paragraph.txt file in documents , but still getting same error , at breakpoints i see everything is good till writeToFile function, filename is valid,everything seems fine but function get error.
help me if u know sty